# WebView forbidden class name for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, classname

I have created an `NSObject` subclass without any implementation and named it "WebView".
In my code I need to be able to dynamicly instantiate objects of this class using `NSClassFromString`.

While it seams like a trivial work, I am having problems with this specific class name "WebView".
It seams like `NSClassFromString()` is failing for this specific class name, but with lldb I can print both class1 and class2 descriptions and for both it says "WebView".

Anyone else experiencing same issue? Is there some list of forbidden class name like it is for instance variables etc?

```
@interface WebView : NSObject
@end

@implementation WebView
@end

@implementation ViewController
- viewDidLoad {
    Class class1 = [WebView class];
    Class class2 = NSClassFromString(NSStringFromClass(class1));

    NSAssert(class1 == class2, @"Classes not equal"); // FAIL
}
@end
```

And another example:

```
[class1 new]; // OK
[class2 new]; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)
```

Comment: WebView is private class used in UIWebView internally, that might cause your problems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

When I try to allocate the WebView. It looks into apple's internal framework as shown in image.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use a three letter prefix for your classes to avoid conflicts like this. Apple reserves all two letter prefixes for itself.

When creating your project in Xcode, it will even ask you what prefix you would like to use and it will create new classes using that prefix for you.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Apple recommends to use three letter prefixes, but reserves only a few with two letters (e.g. NS, UI, AB, CA, CI).

Comment: Pretty sure they reserve all two letter prefixes because they may start using new prefixes in future versions of the OSes. The ones you list are just the examples they include in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html But of course they use others CM -> Core Motion, CG -> Core Graphics, SK -> Sprite Kit (an example of a new prefix they just added in iOS 7).

Answer (score 0):

WebView is the instance apple sdk class. When i used `UIWebView` i was seen webView class how ancestor `UIWebView`. So, do not use class with name WebView, this name use the apple.